# Set release tag_name from contents of file in gitlab-ci.yaml

Tags: gitlab, yaml, environment-variables, gitlab-ci, release

I have the following config for a release:

```
release:
  stage: Release  
  script:
    - echo "Release running"
  release:
    tag_name: $VERSION
    name: 'Release $VERSION'
    description: 'Release created using the Gitlab release-cli.'
```

I'm trying to set the `tag_name` to the contents of `VERSION.txt` which is a semantic version number:

```
1.56.0
```

It appears that Gitlab doesn't allow you to create a variable from a script, for example this doesn't work:

```
variables:
  VERSION: $(cat VERSION.txt)
```

It also appears that exporting the variable from the job's `script` key doesn't work (it isn't available inside `tag_name` and resolves to nothing.

```
script: 
 - export VERSION="$(cat VERSION.txt)"
 - echo $VERSION # outputs 1.56.0 

release:
 tag_name: '${VERSION}' # $VERSION is empty
```

The same is true for `before_script`:

```
before_script: 
 - export VERSION="$(cat VERSION.txt)"
 - echo $VERSION # outputs 1.56.0

release:
 tag_name: '${VERSION}' # $VERSION is empty
```

I have also tried `cat VERSION.txt` within `tag_name` but this isn't executed:

```
release:
 tag_name: '${cat VERSION.txt}' # Tag is literally '${cat VERSION.txt}'
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot directly use variable with the release keyword (see this issue https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/237893)

Alternative 1:

- forgot about the "release" keyword and instead launch the release script yourself using `release-cli`:

```
release_job:
  stage: release
  image: registry.gitlab.com/gitlab-org/release-cli:latest
  script:
    - read -r versionNumberYouWant < ./path/to/your/file
    - echo "Launching the release $versionNumberYouWant"
    - release-cli create --description "Your description" --tag-name $versionNumberYouWant
```

Alternative 2:

- use 2 different jobs. The first job will get the value and save it in a "dotenv" file. The second will apply it. Demo: https://gitlab.com/jaime/hello/-/blob/v1.9.1-rc3/.gitlab/ci/release-from-tag.yml